# How to automatically create a 1:1 relationship?

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a model `User` that hasOne `UserSettings` record related to it (one to one). I want to make it so that when I create a `User` it **automatically** creates a record in `UserSettings` table with default values.

I tried a whole bunch of different combinations of hooks (beforeCreate, beforeValidate, afterCreate). Nothing seemed to work.

It works when I call User.create and include the UserSettings relationship but I dont want to have to pass in the default objects and add the "include".

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I had a 1:m + n:m association but I think that wont be a Problem for your Case.
At the moment I don't know if there is an Automatic Function for that but I did it with that workaround.
In my Case it was
Key 1 : m Lang
Key n:m Products
At the moment I created a Key I went with the Result and Created with the Resulted ID new Langs.
After that created Keys with the Associated Products.

```
export function create(req, res) {
  return DictKey.create(req.body.body)// Create a Key
    .then((res)=> {
      for (var i = 0; i < req.body.langs.length; i++) {
        DictValue.create({//Create Associated Languages 
          lang_id: req.body.langs[i],
          key_id: res._id
        })
      }
      return res;
    })
    .then((key)=>{
      return key.addProduct(req.body.products);//Create Products
    })
    .then(respondWithResult(res, 201))
    .catch(handleError(res));
}
```

In your Model Definition you can set Default Values so u dont need to pass anything.

```
'use strict';

export default function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('dict_Keys', {
    _id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    type: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull:false,
      defaultValue: 0 // DefaultValue if nothing is passed
    },
  },{
    tableName: 'Keys'
  });
}
```

So in your case it could be something like

```
export default function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('UserSettings', {
    _id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    YourColumnName: {
      type: DataTypes.WhatYouWant,
      allowNull:CaseYouNeed,
      defaultValue: 0 // DefaultValue if nothing is passed
    }
}


   export function create(req, res) {
      return User.create(req.body)// Create a User
        .then((res)=> {
          UserSettings.create(
           //Create Associated Settings
           //send with Values or without which the DefaultValues will handle
)
          }
          return res;
        })
        .then(respondWithResult(res, 201))
        .catch(handleError(res));
    }
```

I hope this helps you .

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for more of a before/after hook that would do it every time an instance is created.